# При импорте данных с помощью IMPORTRANGE граница диапазона заранее неизвестна

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Существуют две таблицы Google Sheets, первая содержит список, допустим, фамилий, которыми заполнен столбец A, вторая импортирует данные из первой таблицы и выбирает случайным образом только одно значение:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...; "A1:A20");RANDBETWEEN(1;ROWS(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...";"A1:A20"))))
```

Можно зайти в таблицу, из которой импортируются данные, и посмотреть границы диапазона, а затем добавить в качестве аргумента в функцию IMPORTRANGE второй таблицы. Но т.к. список фамилий изменяется во времени, т.е. меняется количество заполненных ячеек в диапазоне (сегодня диапазон A1:A20, завтра A1:A120), это не совсем удобно. Есть ли какой-то способ вычислять границу диапазона и вставлять ее в функцию IMPORTRANGE, чтобы это все происходило автоматически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/";"NameOfList!A1"
&
":A"
&
СЧЁТЗ(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/";"NameOfList!A1:A")))
```

Иначе говоря, делаем импортрэндж с документа ХХХ, с предопределенным наименованием листа, в диапазоне с началом А1, и концом в А(соединить с количеством не пустых значений в диапазоне ХХХ с предопределенным листом, в диапазоне A1:A)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]